# Remove the header of List of Listings

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, listings, classicthesis

I'm using `classichtesis` and I would like to remove the header of List of Listings.

Before posting here, I tried the following strategies:

- The command `\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{}`, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814714/how-to-change-title-in-listings), makes disappear also the title of the list.
- The command `\markboth{}{}` doesn't work.
- The command `\thispagestyle{empty}` before `\begingroup` or `\lstlistoflistings` doesn't work.

Here is the code I'm using:

**EDIT:** Added some more information.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\let\newcounter\@gobble\let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
\globaldefs\@ne \let\c@loldepth\@ne
\newlistof{listings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
\endgroup
\let\l@lstlisting\l@listings
\let\lstlistoflistings\listoflistings
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftlistingspresnum}{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase}
\renewcommand{\cftlistingsfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftlistingsleader}{\hspace{1.5em}}
\renewcommand{\cftlistingspresnum}{Algorithm~}
\renewcommand{\cftlistingsafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforelistingsskip}{\cftbeforesecskip}
\newlength{\listingslabelwidth}
\settowidth{\listingslabelwidth}{\cftlistingspresnum~99}
\addtolength{\listingslabelwidth}{2.5em}
\cftsetindents{listings}{0em}{\listingslabelwidth}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Algorithms}
\def\lstlistingautorefname{Algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\vspace*{5ex}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\vspace*{5ex}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Listings}
\lstlistoflistings

\endgroup

\clearpage

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={First listing}]
for i = 1,...,n:
    print 'Hello'
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Second listing}]
for i = 1,...,n:
    print 'Goodbye'
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

By compiling it, you can find the header of List of Listings in the second page. In my thesis is actually in the same page of List of Listings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to your document preamble,

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftmarklol}{%
  \@mkboth{}{}%
}
\makeatother
```

This overrides the usual definition:

```
\@mkboth{\lstlistoflistingname}{\lstlistoflistingname}
```

Note that you  may have to do this for other "List of ..."'s as well. In your MWE, the List of Listings (or Algorithms) actually overwrites and empties the header and since everything fits on a single page it works. However, if you other "List of ..."'s together span more than one page, it may require some work.

Comment: @mp87: the code provided by Werner must be enclosed inside `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` (`\makeatother` is missing in your code).